# Conversion of python code to java

Tags: java, python

I want to convert following python code to java -

```
def get_ginger_url(text):
"""Get URL for checking grammar using Ginger.

source: https://github.com/zoncoen/python-ginger

@param text English text
@return URL
"""
API_KEY = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

scheme = "http"
netloc = "services.gingersoftware.com"
path = "/Ginger/correct/json/GingerTheText"
params = ""
query = urllib.urlencode([
    ("lang", "US"),
    ("clientVersion", "2.0"),
    ("apiKey", API_KEY),
    ("text", text)])
fragment = ""

return(urlparse.urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment)))
```

I know I should do it.But my every try failed.

This is the java code -

```
package ginger;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    try{                         
        //connections settings
        String data = "I am eating an apple";
        URL url = new URL("http://services.gingersoftware.com/Ginger/correct/json/GingerTheText?lang=US&clientVersion=2.0&apiKey=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX&data=");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput (true);             
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        //make the request
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());                
        writer.write(data);                
        writer.flush(); 

        //read the request
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Error I am getting is - Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL

Please help me for this conversion.

Thank you

Comment: That's a little vague at the moment. What's going wrong? Also - the whitespace in the python doesn't look right, I presume it's missing some indentation. Which specific trouble are you having? What are you trying ot use in Java? Why do you want to re-write this in Java?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611790/how-do-i-translate-python-urllib-request-code-to-java-code)

Comment: Sorry for that. I want to use ginger grammar checking api in java.But I don't know how to.Can you please tell me.

Comment: That might be a much better title - to avoid downvotes - and you might not want to share your API key. Can you post any atttempts you have in Java too, to make the question more specific?